# How to do this more efficiently

Tags: php

Currently I'm using this code:

```
<?php
/*
Clean, Simple, Minimal.
*/
$pages = array('home', 'login', 'register', 'logout', 'test');
if (isset($_GET['p']))
{
    $page = $_GET['p'];
    if (in_array($page, $pages))
    {
       include('pages/' . $page . '.php');
    }
} 
 else {
    echo 'Hi';
}
?>
```

I want this to be as secure and efficent as possible, I've seen multiple versions of this. I wasn't sure how to do what i really wanted,  i wanted it so, if the requested file .php exists in /pages/ it'll show it, else throw error. But last time i did that i was vulnerable to LFI.

Comment: Why not use a proper framework? ;)

Comment: @TheifMaster probably because most frameworks are not `Clean, Simple, Minimal.`, nah just kidding :)

Comment: This should be on [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: <off>@ThiefMaster If you do not know how the frameworks work, you should not use them. One of the best way to understand the problems that the frameworks face with is to try to implement them. On the other hand, a framework could be inefficient (for example for small sites)</off>

Comment: @ThiefMaster Usage of a framework depends on wether the programmer has experience with a framework and how big the project itself is. If there is not a lot of experience with frameworks existing and the project itself is small then adding a framework could end up in trippling the size of the project (timewise) or even worse. And even then the size of the project is increased considerably. For experience with frameworks Will Econ would have to say if he has experience there or not.

Comment: I would also pass the strict parameter to `in_array`

Comment: Since you validate `$pages`, how is it  vulnerable to LFI ?

Comment: Theoretically he could also "just" use a switch statement (instead of the array and if) if its just a handful of pages. @Will Econ can you explain a bit more there thus if it is only a handful of preset pages or if the number of pages can grow in time (thus more come to it) or how many pages in total are planed there? That COULD affect a few possible solutions.

Comment: @Thomas you cannot do strict checking in a `switch` statement

Comment: @Will Econ i tried executing the code given by you, but was not able to understand what problem you are facing, can you please explain in brief.

Comment: @Will Econ If you only need error, if file do not exist than just add else condition to your if condition for in_array.